# Set condition for layout - CSS

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a page that has default layout with two parts, right-side and left-side. This page show details of an article, if in admin page I set `layout` attribute(for article) to `2` then the page will display as default, if `layout` equal `1` then the right-side should be hidden, and the left-side will show full screen. How should I do with this problem? I use Rails as back end.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Thank you, I think my problem is depending on the setting for `layout` in database, not the changes of screen. So it base on the change of `layout` value not about mobile or pc screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it by using Rails then you could use a method to determine which layout you want to use. This of course required you to have different layout templates.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  layout :determine_layout

  ...

  private

  def determine_layout
    if @article.present? && @article.layout == 1
      :no_right_side # or whatever you choose to name it
    else
      :application # or whatever your default layout is called
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you, but I think if I create two templates, they will be quite the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have two layout within your **application.html.erb**

```
<% if @article.present? && @article.layout == 1 %>
  <!-- your layout 1 -->
<% else %>
  <!-- your layout 2 -->
<% end %>
```